# How can I map dictionary values of only a certain element to a new dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a dictionary that has 2 values for every key:

```
dic = {
'AR': ['Arkansas', 804],
'CA': ['California', 223]
}
```

I am trying to map the dictionary values to a new column in my dataframe called count. However, I only want the numerical element, i.e. 804, 223.

I want my dataframe to look like:

```
date          state      count
2018-01-13      AR        804.0
2018-02-23      CA        223.0
```

I used

```
df['count'] = df['state'].map(dic)
```

And I get

```
date          state      count
2018-01-13      AR       'Arkansas', 804
2018-02-23      CA       'California', 223
```

How can I only map the numerical elements from the values into the dataframe? Ideally I want to use .str[] function to solve this issue but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a lambda function with the map method. Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {
    'AR': ['Arkansas', 804],
    'CA': ['California', 223]
}

data = {'date': ['2018-01-13', '2018-02-23'],
        'state': ['AR', 'CA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['count'] = df['state'].map(lambda x: dic[x][1])

print(df)
```

This is the result:

[image]

And yes, you can use `str` for solution. Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {
    'AR': ['Arkansas', 804],
    'CA': ['California', 223]
}
 
data = {'date': ['2018-01-13', '2018-02-23'],
        'state': ['AR', 'CA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
df['count'] = df['state'].map(dic).str[1]
 
print(df)
```

The result will be same as above.

[You can check on my kaggle here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarsitohang/notebookf534d46634)